# What would be the simplest analogue in OCaml, of Python's enumerate function?

Tags: python, list, ocaml, enumerate, lazy-sequences

In Python enumerate works as follows:

```py
a_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    
for i, x in enumerate(a_list): 
    print(i, x)
```

The output will be:

```
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

Thus, enumerate actually returns a generator (pretty much a lazy sequence) of pairs of the form (i, x) where i ranges over 0, 1, 2, ... and x are the elements of the list in order.

So far I have come up with this definition for lists, which does not produce a "generator" but also a list of pairs:

```
let enumerate (a_list: 'a list): (int * 'a) list =
  let rec _enumerar (a_list: 'a list) (accum: (int * 'a) list) (i: int): (int * 'a) list =
    match a_list with
    | [] -> accum
    | x::xs -> _enumerar  xs ((i, x)::accum) (i+1)
  in
  _enumerar a_list [] 0 |> List.rev
```

Example usage:

```ml
# enumerate ['a'; 'b'; 'c'];;
- : (int * char) list = [(0, 'a'); (1, 'b'); (2, 'c')]
```

Any ideas whether this function perhaps with a different name is implemented anywhere in the standard library or in Base?

What about a lazy version using Sequence or Stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add indices to a list, you can easily do this with `List.mapi (fun i x -> (i,x))`, so that

```
List.mapi (fun i x -> (i,x)) ['a';'b';'c']
```

will return a new list `[0,'a'; 1, 'b'; 2, 'c']`. It is basically what your `enumerate` function is doing.

Of course, it is not a lazy generator. There is the lazy generator module `Seq` in the standard library, but it was added pretty recently so the interface is still developing. Alternatively, you can use the `Sequence` module available in Janestreet's `Base` (and its extension, `Core`), e.g.,

```
open Base

let enumerate xs =
  Sequence.of_list xs |>
  Sequence.mapi ~f:Tuple.T2.create
```

The generated sequence is lazy so the function `enumerate xs` is O(1) that doesn't iterate the list until the sequence is used, e.g.,

```
open Base

let () = enumerate ['a'; 'b'; 'c'] |> Sequence.iter ~f:(fun (i,c) -> 
  printf "%d %c\n" i c
```

Of course, the same could be done easily with, the `Sequence.iteri` or even with `List.iteri` iterators. This brings us to the topic of iterators. In OCaml, as well as in many other functional programming languages, we use iterators, such as `iter`, `map`, and `fold` to express iteration over containers. Most of the tasks could be easily expressed using one of these (and derived from them) iterators so it is rarely necessary to use the pythonic approach that will generate a lot of intermediate data structures.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest OCaml equivalent would be:

```ml
List.iteri (Printf.printf "%d %c\n") ['a'; 'b'; 'c']
```

Python is using a for `loop` and `enumerate` due to its limited support for higher-order functions. By contrast, most enumerable container types in OCaml tend to directly offer a `i` version of iterators, maps and folds.

If you want a more direct translation from Python, the OCaml version of a  generator is a `Seq.t` since both are external iterator:

```ml
   Seq.iter (fun (i,x) -> Printf.printf "%d %c\n" i x)
@@ Seq.mapi (fun i x -> i, x) 
@@ List.to_seq ['a';'b';'c']
```

(forgetting for a time that `Seq.iteri` exists too *as of OCaml 4.14*)

Comment: What do you mean by "Python is using a for loop and enumerate due to its limited support for higher-order functions."?

Comment: Higher-order functions work better when one can easily define function arguments. Python doesn't have a good support for neither anonymous functions (Python lambda are limited to a single statement) nor partial application. This limits the usability of higher-order functions. Consequently, Python code is often structured to use for-loop with on generators rather than higher-order functions.

Comment: Also `List.mapi`: https://v2.ocaml.org/api/List.html#VALmapi.

Comment: True. One difference however is that `List.mapi` creates an intermediary list, which is not the case for `Seq.mapi` and `enumerate`.

Comment: I am not able to find `Seq.mapi`. This is supposed to be in the regular standard library, not in Base, right?  I am using OCaml version 4.13.1  and  `#show Seq;;` doesn't show this function...

Comment: It wasn't added until 4.14.

Answer (score 0):

So from @octachron's answer it seems that the simplest (non lazy) version, without using Base, would be:

```ml
 # let enumerate_list (lst: 'a list) = List.mapi lst ~f:( fun i x -> (i, x)) 
val enumerate_list : 'a list -> (int * 'a) list = <fun>
```

And if we want a lazy version that most closely resembles Python's generator approach, using `Base.Sequence` it would be:

```ml
 # open Base
 # let enumerate(lst: 'a list) =  Sequence.mapi ~f:(fun i x -> (i, x)) 
                                    (Sequence.of_list lst) ;;
```

This way we can make

```
# let enumerated_seq = enumerate ['a'; 'b'; 'c']
val a : (int * char) Sequence.t = <abstr>
```

and if we wanted to materialize a list

```
# let enumerated_list = Sequence.to_list @@ enumerate ['a'; 'b'; 'c']
val a : (int * char) list = [(0, 'a'); (1, 'b'); (2, 'c')]
```